# Error: Permission denied: '/user'

Tags: shell, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, batch-processing

When I'm trying to copy the AWS S3 buckets to HDFS I'm getting the Error:

> Permission denied: '/user'

Below is my script

```
aws s3 sync s3://folder1.folder2/file.json /user/hive/warehouse/my.db/json_table
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

S3 `sync` does not recognize `HDFS` path.

Either use,

- [`hadoop distcp`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) after configuring all the S3 related [properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html).
- [`S3DistCp`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html#UsingEMR_s3distcp.options), this requires `s3distcp.jar`.
- If the files are small, `sync` the files to localpath and `copyFromLocal` to HDFS.

Comment: I've been using `sync` but if I use `S3Distcp` I can reduce a step in moving the data from S3 to HDFS. I did install s3distcp jar but it's throwing me an error.

Comment: You can use Distcp itself if you have the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Regarding the error from `s3distcp`,you can open a new question on that posting the complete stacktrace.